# Java generics grammar

Tags: java, generics, grammar

I couldn't understand the following statement while it is indeed compilable:

```
List<Integer> l = Collections.<Integer>singletonList(5);
```

Say, the second `<Integer>`, how can we put a single `<Integer>` in front of the method name? I suspect it's a declaration of generics but cannot find it anywhere. But I only know the definition such as `List<Integer>`, put `<Integer>` behind a generics type. Can anybody point out me a tutorial for this grammar or find the duplicated question (sorry I didn't find one during my quick search)?

Many thanks!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: Also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: That's indeed what I'm looking for. Thank you! @manouti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a **type witness**, and it is referenced in the [Type Inference trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html):

> The generic method `addBox` defines one type parameter named U. Generally, a Java compiler can infer the type parameters of a generic method call. Consequently, in most cases, you do not have to specify them. For example, to invoke the generic method `addBox`, you can specify the type parameter with a *type witness* as follows:
>
> ```
> BoxDemo.<Integer>addBox(Integer.valueOf(10), listOfIntegerBoxes);
> ```

Effectively, a type witness lets the developer step in to resolve cases in which the type engine can't properly infer what type a value will result in.  You'd see its usage more commonly and prevalently in Java 7, whereas Java 8 has improved its type inference capabilities.

Comment: Thank you! That's definitely helpful!